# How to prevent my server access from timing out while my program is running?

Tags: ssh

I'm running a script through ssh on an external server. My code takes quite a long time to execute. I'm running the script on tmux. But my connection to the server seems to be getting terminated before my script finishes running. Can someone tell me how to prevent my server connection from terminating while my code runs?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmiAZ.jpg)

Here is what it looks like when my connection to the server breaks